# Change the capture group order from .match()

Tags: javascript, regex, match, wildcard, capture

In JS, if I have a Regexp like:

`new RegExp('^(.*?) in the year ([0-9]{1,4})$|^([0-9]{1,4}) is the year$')`

Then how do I ensure that the "year" portion is always the same capture group, so that I can access it like `matches[2]`? At the moment, if the first part of the RegExp is matched, then the year is `matches[2]`, but in the second part it is `matches[1]`. I'd like to instead make them the same, so that I can consistently retrieve the same value.

Also keep in mind that I want to still capture the `(.*?)` in the beginning, so simply removing the parens there won't help me.

Comment: do you use those other capture groups? or can we make them non-capture groups?  the "dirty" solution would be the following `^(.*?) in the year ([0-9]{1,4})$|^()([0-9]{1,4}) is the year$`  a much more clean solution would be to break the above into two regex calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The year will never be in `matches[1]`. Capture group numbers are assigned based on the entire regexp, not by which alternative matches. If one of the alternatives doesn't match, all its capture groups will be null.

So if the first alternative matches, the year will be in `matches[2]`. If the second alternative matches, it will be in `matches[3]`. You can then get the year from whichever matched with:

```
var year = matches[2] || matches[3];
```

BTW, there's no need to use `new RegExp` when the regexp is a literal string. Use a RegExp literal

```
/^(.*?) in the year ([0-9]{1,4})$|^([0-9]{1,4}) is the year$/
```